# Setup blender cycles so that it shows svg images as they would normally look

Tags: light, color, svg

I have created an svg image in inkscape. In blender (cycles) I've imported the svg image but the colors are not ok:

[image]

How do you setup blender cycles so that it renders the imported svg the same as in inkscape or any other svg viewer?

(reason for svg: to animate the separate objects/layers)

- I tried to remove the lamp --> dark, nothing visible
- I tried changing lamp type --> almost no difference
- setting the World surface color to white gives me the correct white background already
- Scene > uncheck Shadows in Light paths, does not really do much.

What should be enabled/disabled to correctly display the svg images?

Answer (score 4):

As you describe it, you just want to import into blender for animation purposes.

I might be wrong, but I think blender only looks at the shapes of the svgs and (based on your image) approximates the color gradients as single colors. I suggest exporting all svgs as png with alpha and use the "import image as plane add-on" in blender. [addon](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Planes_from_Images)

Set the materials on the planes to an emission shader with strength 1 (this way they are "not shaded" and somewhat independent of external lighting, giving a 2d look) and the background to white.

[image]

[image]

Comment: purpose of svg is when I scale them, they look good… (vector) compared to png...